# What doe the error XX does not exist on type 'never' for VUE3 mean?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Could some explain the error I get below. If I use ref(null) I get this error but with anything I don't. What is the correct way to call null and avoid the error?

**Property 'scrollHeight' does not exist on type 'never'.**

**Property 'clientHeight' does not exist on type 'never'.**

```
const information = ref(null) // Throws error
const information = ref() // No error


function informationRefStatus() {
  const element = information.value
  isTextTruncated.value = element?.scrollHeight > element?.clientHeight
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a TypeScript error, not specific to Vue.  If you don't specify a type it becomes inferred based on the initial value.

```
const information = ref()
```

The type here is inferred to be `Ref<any>`, where [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is a type indicating it can be *any value* and TypeScript will not do any further typechecking on it, so you can treat the inner ref value as a string or a number or an HTML element and TypeScript will be fine with it. That's why you have no error. After being declared as `any`, TypeScript basically ignores it.

```
const information = ref(null)
```

This infers a type of `Ref<null>` which means `information` is always expected to have an inner ref value of `null`.  Null **never** has any properties associated with it, so when you try to reference one such as `scrollHeight` it leads to your error.

When you use TypeScript you are agreeing to follow the restrictions of using a strongly typed language. Typed variables can only be used as those types, and using them in any other way will throw errors.  If `information` is an HTML element that is initially null, then you should type that variable as such

```js
const information = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

function informationRefStatus() {
  if (information.value) { // check that information is not still null
    const element = information.value
    isTextTruncated.value = element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight
  }
}
```